# How to cut out the Values from a list of Key-Value pairs

Tags: python, bash, text, awk

I have a file with multiple KV pairs.

Input:

```
$ cat input.txt
k1:v1 k2:v2 k3:v3
...
```

I am only interested in the values. The keys (name) are just to remember what each value meant. Essentially I am looking to `cut` the keys out so that I can plot the value columns.

Output:

```
$ ...
v1 v2 v3
```

Is their a single-liner bash command that can help me achieve this?

UPDATE

---

This is how I am currently doing it (looks ugly)

```
>> cat input.txt | python -c "import sys; \
   lines = sys.stdin.readlines(); \
   values = [[i.split(':')[1] for i in item] for item in \
   [line.split() for line in lines]]; \
   import os; [os.system('echo %s'%v) for v in \
   ['\t'.join(value) for value in values]]" > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

is this ok for you?

```
sed -r 's/\w+://g' yourfile
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "k1:v1 k2:v2 k3:v3"|sed -r 's/\w+://g'                                    
v1 v2 v3
```

**update**
well, if your key contains "-" etc: see below

```
kent$  echo "k1#-$%-^=:v1 k2:v2 k3:v3"|sed -r 's/[^ ]+://g'  
v1 v2 v3
```

Comment: does this assume that my key cannot have numbers or dashes? when I run it on the input, some of the keys are not completely eliminated. For example, `x-y-2012:v1`

Comment: Is there a way to say anything but whitespace with sed, to get the tab in the [^ ] as well?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v FS=':' -v RS=' ' -v ORS=' ' '{print $2}' foo.txt
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators

Comment: You can use a `BEGIN` block: `awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":"; RS = ORS = " "} {print $2}' foo.txt

Comment: Also, `-F:` is equivalent to setting `FS`.

Answer (score 1):

I see `sed`, `awk` and `python`, so here's plain `bash`:

```
while IFS=' ' read -a kv ; do printf '%s ' "${kv[@]#*:}" ; done < input.txt
```

Just for good measure, here's a `perl` version:

```
perl -n -e 'print(join(" ",values%{{@{[split(/[:\s]/,$_)]}}})," ")' < input.txt
```

The order of the values changes, though, so it's probably not going to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with **awk**:

```
awk '{split($0,p," "); for(kv in p) {split(p[kv],a,":"); printf "%s ",a[2];} print ""}' foo.txt
```

Comment: AWK gives you the first split for free.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Input.txt**

k1:v1 k2:v2 k3:v3

**Code**

```
 awk -F " " '{for( i =1 ; i<=NF ;i+=1) print $i}' Input.txt | cut -d ":" -f 2 | tr '\n' ' '
```

**Output**

v1 v2 v3